# How to execute code in order in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute some code in order, but cannot get it to work. What I want to do is:

```
var validate = function($form) {
    $form
        .find('[data-required]')
        .each(function() {
            if(Util.isEmpty($(this).val())) {
                $(this).addClass('error');
                Util.Notify(Util.ERROR, $(this).data('required'));
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('error');
            }
        });
};

var submit = function($form) {
  $.post(actionUrl, $form.serialize(), function(response) {
    //...
  });
};

validate(); // must execute first with no False return
submit();   // must execute second and only if validate() not returns False
```

However, my $.post() gets executed even if validate() returns false. How can I force submit() to be executed after validate is executed and did not return false? I googled and tried a few example based on what people posted, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: `validate` doesn't return anything.  Also you're not passing it any parameters even though it expects one.  You need to have `validate` return something then you can do `if(validate()){ submit(); }`

Comment: First off, you're returning from `.each`'s callback and not `validate`.

Comment: General formula should be `if(validate()) { submit(); }`. To make this work, `validate` should return `true` (validated) or `false` (not validated).

Comment: For a validation like this, you may wish to consider the Validation Plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call `submit()` from within `validate()` when the conditions are correct, or you could do this:

```
if(validate()) {
    submit(); 
}
```

Just make sure `validate()` returns something when not false, so the if evaluates as `true`...

Also make sure that the `return` is on the right place, the way it is now, it's returning from the anonymous function inside `.each()`, as Fabrício Matté mentioned...

Comment: Just a side note to this code - if submission is triggered by a `submit` type button the default behavior of the form needs to be prevented with `preventDefault()` (http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) otherwise the form will be submitted even if its not valid.

Comment: Actually, it's only *trying* to return from the anonymous function inside `.each()`. In reality, returning anything falsy from an `.each()` callback is the same as `break` in a `for` loop - ie. the loop terminates immediately.

Comment: That was my error then. For some reason I thought that by returning false from each(), returns false from validate() too. I see it now. Thanks.